# Paper publishing as a regular software engineer

Tags: publications, paper-submission

I have a strange request - I am looking for ways to get started on publishing a few papers in a couple of years. Ideally looking to collaborate with researchers/professors to contribute to their work and ideally become co-author in some capacity. Is this a reasonable route ? If yes, where can I look for such opportunities ?

**My background**

I am a regular software engineer. I currently work at one of the [FAANG's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Tech) at a fairly senior role (IC7) and have 10+ years of experience working on large scale systems & databases. I am self taught and I do not have a research background so a bit confused on how to go about this.

**Why am I doing this ?**

I am starting a perilous journey working towards building a case for EB1-A visa, I already satisfy few of the criteria and looking to improve my profile over the next few years, it is a long shot but unfortunately this is as good as it gets for me to get a green card in a reasonable period.

Appreciate your help !

Comment: To be honest, that motivation (as opposed to an interest in some field) sounds much less reasonable than the plan to collaborate with established researchers. Regarding where to look, maybe [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/137481) can help. Also note that your employer may or may not be fine with your plan.

Comment: @Anyon can you explain what is wrong with the motivation?

Comment: @DanRomik While I can't speak for Anyon, the problem that I see with the motivation is that it is, according to the description in the question, completely extrinsic. I have some doubts whether this is a good foundation for doing research.

Comment: @JochenGlueck so what? Extrinsic motivation also caused Gauss to set aside pure math for a while in 1801 and work on computing the position of Ceres, recently discovered but then lost by astronomers. His solution enabled astronomers to find Ceres again, and propelled him to scientific superstardom. (See the book Men of Mathematics by E.T. Bell.) People do many great things out of extrinsic motivation. The cynic in me would say that even you and I are likely guilty of taking extrinsic rewards into account at some point in our careers. Isn't it hypocritical to fault OP for doing the same?

Comment: @DanRomik: Sure, extrinsic motivation is obviously relevant almost always in life. I can assure you that I do a lot of things, also as a mathematician, out of extrinsic motivation. The point in my comment was the word *completely*. If somebody wants to do research *merely* out of extrinsic motivation, I think this is unlikely (though not impossible) to work out well. If Gauss had had no intrinsic desire to do math and had worked on any math problems merely out of extrinsic motivation, I doubt that he would have ever obtained all the experience that he used to find the position of Ceres.

Comment: That said, I have to admit that it might be a bit unfair to claim that OP has no intrinsic motivation to do research. After all, I have no way to know whether this is the case - I just find it a bit worrisome that intrinsic motivation is not mentioned at all in the question.

Comment: (1) Do you really need to collaborate with "researchers/professors"? There are forums related to software engineering, complex systems, etc. that might let you publish with less ramp-up then getting involved in academic research. (2) Lots of great papers are published by the FAANGs every year.  Have you considered getting some of your time allocated to support such efforts? This seems more reasonable to me than doing a ton of research "in your spare time."

Comment: @DanRomik I think Jochen's comments sum it up well. The fact that the question only mentions an extrinsic reward is worrisome, especially for something presumably done in one's free time. Personally I would find it weird to be contacted by someone under such terms, but as your answer shows others would react differently. I also interpreted "few" in the question as at least 3, which is the minimum number of met criteria for that type of green card, in which case the reward would seem fairly minor as well. But I guess some use "few" to mean 2+, so the reward could be more substantial than that.

Answer (score 2):

Given your career success and credentials, it certainly sounds like you possess a level of talent and professional competence that would make it possible for you to make useful contributions in research. So yes, it sounds absolutely like a reasonable idea. But you are correct that it is an unconventional place to start from. I think the main difficulty would be getting your feet in the door of academia and finding experienced researchers who would have use for your specific skills. I’m convinced that such people exist though.<sup>*</sup> The labor of a professional software engineer is worth — well, you probably know better than me how much it’s worth — and if you would offer it for free, I’m sure that would be appealing to some people.

Of course, you would also want to get involved in the writing of any publications that would follow from the work. Given your background, you might need a bit of help in that department, but probably only very little, and you should still be quite attractive to the right people as a collaborator.

In terms of where to look for opportunities, I don’t have very specific suggestions, but if you are in the Bay Area (as I’m guessing you may be), there are several world-famous universities around with great activities in computer science, so I’d suggest cold-emailing people at those departments and explaining your situation and interests. You can also probably find people in your current company who have a leg in the academic world and can offer you advice and maybe introductions to relevant people. By reaching out to random (but not completely randomly selected) people and a bit of networking, I think the chances of finding a project you can help with are pretty good.

<sup>* Actually I am such a person, although in an unusual sense that may not be exactly the sort of thing you had in mind. You can email me for details though.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

> Ideally looking to collaborate with researchers/professors to
> contribute...

Let's be pragmatic: researchers are doing research, professors are research manager, they almost do not perform research, they keep the overview on the many small steps performed by PhDs/PostDocs, write the usual breakthrough papers summing up 2-5 years of research and getting lauded for that by popular press.

I say all this without downplaying their importance, on the contrary, to stress you have to get in touch with professors.

You have a senior technical role, you have no time to perform research but you can provide two very important things:

- experience, since you easily keep the overview on plausibility/industrial feasibility/interest on a certain topic of **your** choice;
- money;

The logical conclusion is: you can be co-author because of these two contributions you can bring. How? build a shortlist of professors dealing with topic you worked in the past 5 years, get the funds to pay for their research (i.e. for their PhD students), closely supervise their work, keep thinking about how their work can impact your work.

Since you have a personal interest/goal, explore the feasibility of starting your own small company (0 employees, privately funded by you, to get a very rough order of magnitude estimation keep in mind a PhD costs about 50k $/£/€ per year, senior PhDs are expected to publish 1 paper per year) and propose your small company as funding body for small research projects at your shortlisted professors. Set clear goals, like publications, in advance.

Either this way, or you manage to squeeze R&D money from your company to tackle a relevant problem you are facing now and solving it would provide you a clear commercial advantage against your competitors ...

Ps: side question: how much did you spend for the last car you bought? are you ready to spend the same money to increase your visa chances, while at the same time progressing our knowledge in a certain topic?